# studentized residuals in nonlinear regression

Tags: r, residuals, nls

I am using the nls function in R to perform a nonlinear regression and need to calculate the studentized residuals.  Is this something I need to manually do?  It seems like I need to manually do a QR decomposition and calculate the hat matrix to do this.  I don't have a problem doing this but I wanted to ask if anyone knew an easier way to do this.

Comment: Internally or externally studentized?

Comment: This is a homework related question and it's not specified but I would assume internally.

Comment: the package `nlreg` (for heteroskedastic nonlinear regression) has a function (`nlreg.diag`) that can return a variety of such things including studentized residuals; I don't know much about it but it might be able to do ordinary nonlinear regression for you.